# dBA conversion into dB or dB SPL

Tags: sound, decibel

I saw many websites that how to convert dBA sound to Db and dB SPL conversion. but I did not find any such relationship to convert dBA into dB or dBSPL.
Is there any such formula or relationship that convert dBA into dB and dB SPL?

Comment: So what do you mean by dBA? A-weighted sound pressure level, or something else?

Comment: What is Db please?

Comment: @Andyaka One semi-tone below D.

Comment: Hehehe cubed and squared.

Comment: You can't without frequency information. dBA is a weighted curve with different weightings for each frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Single A-weighted dB value for sound pressure level cannot be undone to unweighted dB value because the single value does not include information about which frequencies exist in the measurement to undo the weighting. Same goes converting a single unweighted measurements to weighted. If you do know the measurements for whole frequency spectrum, and if it is weighted or unweighted, then from that information, it is possible to calculate the other one. Except that it may be difficult to undo weights that are at quite a low amplitude.